# Как установить pypy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypy

Искал, гуглил, читал - в итоге ничего не понял...
Как установить pypy, и использовать его?

Comment: Скачать архив, распаковать, запустить интерперетатор (или нужный скрипт с помощью интерпретатора  через командную строку).

Comment: @insolor я скачал, но опять же, как открывать скрипты? Я так понял нужно как то заново библиотеки ставить, или что то типо того?